# What is the 'iterator' function in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, iterator, firebug

In Firebug, when looking at a `getElementsByTagName` array, which is of type `HTMLCollection` I see the following functions listed:

- `item()`
- `iterator()`
- `namedItem()`

I know how to use `item(number of item)` and `namedItem(name of item)`. But what is the use of iterator() ?

I couldn't find an answer, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the method JavaScript calls when you iterate over an object using a [for…of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, for instance.

See:
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:iterators#for-of_loop_bodies

An example:

```
var myobj = {
  iterator: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      yield i;
  }
}

for (let value of myobj)
  console.log(value);
```

See also [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

In case of an `HTMLCollection` it helps you to write code like:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let div of divs) {
  // do something with `div`
}
```